# How can I enable logs with Memgraph MAGE docker image?

Tags: memgraphdb, memgraph

I've downloaded Memgraph Lab desktop app. When I start it it says to run Memgraph using `docker run -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 memgraph/memgraph-mage`.

This works for my, but I don't see any logs.

I tried to add [log level](https://memgraph.com/docs/configuration/configuration-settings#other)l `docker run -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 --log-level=INFO memgraph/memgraph-mage`. I get the error message `unknown flag: --log-level`. I get the same message for all log levels: `TRACE`, `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARNING`, `ERROR`, `CRITICAL`. Do I need to use Memgraph Lab within docker?